# Can't compile a C program in Windows 7 with MinGW make

Tags: c, windows, makefile, mingw

I want to compile a C program from GitHub on Windows 7 and get an error that a file is not found. I have installed MinGW Make and its dependancies. I think maybe this program is only intended to run on Linux.

The Console output:

```
E:\work-c\iso2opl-clone\iso2opl>make
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -usr\include -usr\local\inc
lude -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -c isofs.c -o isofs.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -F:\programs\mingw\i
nclude -F:\programs\mingw\local\include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SO
URCE -c isofs.c -o isofs.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
make: *** [isofs.o] Erreur 2
```

the makefile:

```
CC = gcc


CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -pedantic -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#CFLAGS += -DDEBUG

ifeq ($(_WIN32),1)
    CFLAGS += -D_WIN32
endif

OBJS = isofs.o \
iso2opl.o

all: $(TARGET)

rm-elf:
    -rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -r $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

I don't know maybe the paths are wrongs.

Best Regards

Comment: Did you consider installing [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your laptop? It could make your life simpler, and you could compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`; see also https://april.org/

Comment: You are correct this makefile expects to be run on a POSIX-based system, such as GNU/Linux or MacOS.  I'm not sure what your question is...?

Comment: Did you try to change the `CC` to `mingw-gcc`, `mingw32-gcc` or `mingw64-gcc` and remove `-I` flags?

Comment: `-usr\include` is an incorrect switch

Comment: Just for clarification: I am suggesting to remove the whole -I options (with aruments) from the Makefile, in most cases MinGW does not need them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the `make` in the MSYS2 shell (https://www.msys2.org/). I was able to build the sources from https://github.com/arcadenea/iso2opl without issue.